# Unable to update the text of a RootElement when used with a modal RadioGroup Section with MonoTouch Dialog

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am creating an `iPad` app using `MonoTouch 2.10.11` and I want to `MonoTouch.Dialog` to create some of the editable fields on a form.  One of the fields will use a `RadioGroup` to allow the user to select from a list of options.  The default behavior of `M.T.D` is display the selection list table over the existing table.  This works great for the `iPhone` layout, but on this `iPad` form, the table is only on a small area of the form and the navigation bar looks odd on the middle of the form.  I want to display the selection as a full screen modal and the user will hit a "back" button to go back the previous form with the selected item.

I created a new `RootElement` descendant class like this:

```
public class ModalRootElement : RootElement 
{    
    public override void Selected (DialogViewController dvc, UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath path)
    {
        tableView.DeselectRow (path, false);
        UIViewController uIViewController = this.MakeViewController ();
        this.PrepareDialogViewController (uIViewController);
        dvc.PresentViewController (uIViewController, true, null);
    }

    protected override void PrepareDialogViewController(UIViewController dvc)
    {
        base.PrepareDialogViewController(dvc);

        UIButton button = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
        button.Frame = new RectangleF (5, 5, 80, 20);
        button.SetTitle ("back", UIControlState.Normal);
        button.TouchUpInside += delegate {
            DialogViewController d = dvc as DialogViewController;

            (d.Root as ModalRootElement).TableView.ReloadData ();

            d.DeactivateController(true);
        };
        dvc.View.AddSubview (button);
    }
}
```

The table is implemented with the following code:

```
var _status = new ModalRootElement("Status", new RadioGroup("status", -1)) {
    (new Section() {
        new RadioElement("New", "status"),
        new RadioElement("In process", "status"),
        new RadioElement("Rejected", "status"),
        new RadioElement("Deferred", "status"),
        new RadioElement("Transferred", "status"),
        new RadioElement("Unknown", "status"),
        new RadioElement("Complete", "status")
    })
};

var _odom = new EntryElement ("Odometer", "current odom", "");
_odom.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.DecimalPad;
_odom.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Right;

var root = new RootElement ("back") {
    new Section("") {
        _status,
        _odom
    }
};

_dvc = new DialogViewController(root);
_nav = new UINavigationController (_dvc);
_nav.SetNavigationBarHidden (true, false);
```

When I run the app, I can drill into the `RadioGroup` and make a selection.  When I click the back button that I added to the view, the modal view closes and the `RadioSelected` properted of the `ModalRootElement` object is set correctly, but the text is not displayed.

If I change `Selected()` method to call `dvc.ActivateController` instead of `PresentViewController`, the `ModalRootElement` displays the correct text, but the `RadioGroup` table has the wrong size. Is there a way to get the `RootElement` to display the correct text when you use `PresentViewController` instead of `ActivateController`?

Comment: This isn't really an answer so I'm leaving it as a comment. Have you tried `PushViewController`? then you can `PopViewController` later. Also, you can create your own `RadioElement` inheriting from the RadioElement Class. This will allow you to have an event that you can wire up to and set the index of the text in the radiogroup on your previous screen. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a Root.Reload() call.